# ASP.Net Core posting list from ajax to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am able to send a single complex type from ajax to controller however not able to pass a list, always comes up null.  *** Code has been updated to show successful passing.

```csharp
public class EntityAliasTest
{
  public int IDTEMP1 { get; set; }
  public string NAMETEMP1 { get; set; }
}
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveEntityAliases([FromBody] 
List<EntityAliasTest> postData)
{
  var es = ModelState.SerializeErrors();
  return Json(new[] { postData, es });
}
```

```js
var aliasList = new Array();

var o = { IDTEMP1 : 0, NAMETEMP1: 'test 0' };
aliasList.push(o);

o = { IDTEMP1 : 1, NAMETEMP1: 'test 1' };
aliasList.push(o);

o = { IDTEMP1 : 2, NAMETEMP1: 'test 2' };
aliasList.push(o);

var postData= JSON.stringify(aliasList);

$.ajax({
  url: "DataAdministration/EntityAlias/SaveEntityAliases",
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: postData,
}).done(function (data) {
```

Comment: At first glance your code seems fine. Have you checked the console for errors or added any error handling code to see what the response from the request is?

Comment: I have updated the code to show it passing successfully.  Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your ajax call, you are sending a single object that contains a list. So your controller will also expect an object with that kind of structure.

Instead of this:
var data = { postData: aliasList };
var data2send = JSON.stringify(data);

You can try:
var data2send = JSON.stringify(aliasList);

You can use online json validator to check if you pass a valid json data. You can refer on the link below.

https://jsonlint.com/

Hope it will help.

Comment: I updated and validated the JSON, all is good with it, however still getting null IEnumerable<EntityAliasTest> postData in my controller?  Any thoughts?

Comment: Made a few additional changes but this got me to right spot.  Thanks!  I marked a checked but said something about 15 checks needed?